# Подправить svg на полное очертание окружности

Tags: svg, path

Подправить svg на полное очертание окружности. Сам впервые столкнулся с этим. Сейчас чертит около 70%.

```css
path {
    stroke-dasharray: 191;
    stroke-dashoffset: -191;
    -webkit-animation: dash 1s linear 1 forwards;
    animation: dash 1s linear 1 forwards;
}
@-webkit-keyframes dash {
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes dash {
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 92 92">
  <circle style="opacity:0.16;fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:2;stroke-miterlimit:10;" cx="46" cy="46" r="45"/>
  <path style="fill:none;stroke:#FFFFFF;stroke-width:2;stroke-miterlimit:10;" d="M6.185,66.968C13.725,81.256,28.721,91,46,91c24.853,0,45-20.147,45-45C91,21.147,70.853,1,46,1"/>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Так у вас столько и нарисовано в `<path>`. Вы не сможете нарисовать линию там где ее нет, надо заменить обрезанный `<path>` на фигуру полного круга. Например, если взять `<circle>` вместо `<path>` (circle ведь содержит полный круг, не так-ли?) Подобрать `stroke-dasharray` и `stroke-dashoffset` и вуаля:

```css
.path {
  stroke-dasharray: 283;
  stroke-dashoffset: -283;
  -webkit-animation: dash 1s linear 1 forwards;
  animation: dash 1s linear 1 forwards;
}

@-webkit-keyframes dash {
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes dash {
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}

body {
  background: #999
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 92 92" width=200>
    <circle style="opacity:0.16;fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:2;stroke-miterlimit:10;" cx="46" cy="46" r="45"/>
    <circle class="path" style="fill:none;stroke:#FFFFFF;stroke-width:2;stroke-miterlimit:10;" cx="46" cy="46" r="45" transform="rotate(-90,46,46) scale(1, -1) translate(0,-92)"/>

</svg>
```

Ну и там надо класс какой-то ввести, чтобы определить какой из кругов стилизуется.

> как сделать вращение с верхней точки и в правую сторону?

```
transform="rotate(-90,46,46)"
```

где `46,46` - центр поворота

С разворотом сложнее. C учетом того, что фигура повернута на 90град, нам нужно двигать и масштабировать по оси Y:

```
scale(1, -1) translate(0,-92)
```

Comment: В принципе да, только как сделать вращение с верхней точки и в правую сторону?

Comment: @Rammsteinik, Ответил